# How to use node_modules in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to use node_modules js in Magento2 but there is a require js conflict error.
How can I solved and use node_modules in magento2?

**EDIT:**

requirejs-config.js code:

```
var config = { 
    map: { 
        '*': { 
            lightwallet:'Unitedcrowd_Tokensale/js/lightwallet' 
        } 
    } 
};
```

// This light wallet is using node_modules packages and due to that mismatch error has appeared.

Comment: Can you please share the conflict error here?

Comment: Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function($) {}); I get this error due to not use define() in js. but the I use lightwallet.js and that js require node_modules js and those js are creating a confliction.

Comment: OK, please update your question with requirejs-config.js file. So I cab debug it further.

Comment: @Sumit,
This is my requirejs-config.js code:
`var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lightwallet: 'Unitedcrowd_Tokensale/js/lightwallet'
        }
    }
};`
This lightwallet js is used to node_module js.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, You are able to get node_modules Javascript assets to be available via RequireJS. Using Bootstrap as an example, this is what I did inside my theme folder:

1. Required bootstrap in `package.json` and installed with yarn
2. Created a `symbolic link`: web/node_modules pointing to ../node_modules
3. Created a `requirejs-config.js` file in your theme

[image]

The only downside What I feel is that setup:static-content:deploy takes a bit longer and attempts to compile the .less files in the packages.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. earlier I saw the same post but my problem is I need to use another modules like web3, web3-eth etc. So problem is those js package require lots of all other js from node_modules. So I think it's impossible to create a symbolic link for all of those js

Comment: thanks for sharing but i want to apply "npm install @web3modal/ethers5 ethers@5.7.2" in requires-config.js which file path add.?

Comment: @Adilkadiyawala you get any solution for web3, web3-eth related. if you find any solution so please help me.